# What is the minimum number of edges a graph can have with strongly connected components of at least $3$ vertices each?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

This is a homework question that has me stumped:

> Let $G$ be a **directed graph** with $\boldsymbol n$ vertices and $\boldsymbol k$ strongly connected components (with $1 < k \leq
> \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$). We also know that each strongly connected component has at least $3$ vertices. What is the minimum number of edges that $G$ may have?

I know that if $G$ is a directed graph with $n$ vertices and $k$ strongly connected components (with $k > 1$), the minimum number of edges that $G$ may have can be calculated with: $\boldsymbol{n - k + 1}$.

My initial hunch is that the general formula needs to be modified to account for the strongly connected component with at least $3$ vertices, but I'm not sure which approach to take and, most importantly, what properties to use.

Comment: Have you tried to find examples with at least 3 vertices in each of three strongly connected components?  Of course such "components" might share vertices and directed edges.

Comment: My initial thought is a graph like this: 

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/LoTGLEF.jpg)

So the end result would be n = 6, k = 2 leading to 6 - 2 + 1 = 4 edges. But that doesn't fit the homework question.

Comment: I see only two strongly connected components (vertices must be mutually reachable by directed paths in such a component).  Of course we can give the easy example of three independent 3-cycles, so 9 edges is an upper bound.

Comment: Do you know a _proof_ of the $n-k+1$ formula? That ought to shed some insight on what needs to be modified to account for the additional requirement that each SCC contains at least $3$ vertices.

Comment: @hardmath As I understand it, a strongly connected component cannot share any vertices with another strongly connected component. Complicating matters is each component must have at least 3 vertices. Using the 9 edge example you provided, all components would share one vertex each. I thought of something similar, but it would use 11 edges, with 3 * 3 edges + 2 edges bridging the three strongly connected components.

Comment: http://theory.stanford.edu/~tim/w11/l/scc.pdf

Comment: The title says $3$ strongly connected components but the body says $k$ strongly connected components. Which is it?

Comment: @bof It's k components with at least 3 vertices each. I just edited the title to help clear the confusion.

Comment: It may be assumed in the exercise, but not in the problem stated here, that the underlying simple graph should be connected.  But as here stated there does not seem to be a need for "bridges" between the strongly connected components of  $G$.